# NameID required in SAML Assertion

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

Trying to integrate with an IdP I am getting a failure that a NameID is not present in the Assertion. I noticed on lines 250-253 of processAuthenticationResponse in org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl there is an explicit check for the NameID. I can't find anywhere in the 2.0 spec where a NameID is mandatory. If neither metatdata specifies a NameIDPolicy and the AuthnRequest doesn't specify one, should the check for NameID be optional?

Answer (score 0):

Spring SAML currently requires `NameID` to be present. I agree that adding a feature which makes it optional is reasonable. Please feel free to open a feature request in [Spring SAML Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES/component/10711/).